# What does 'K' mean in '20K' when talking about prices?

Tags: numbers, abbreviations

What is the meaning of 'K' in 20K or 30K or 40K when disclosing price?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

True. The letter is described to show '1000'. The prefix 'kilo' is derived from the Greek word *chilioi or khilioi*. Its short form was used for the metric system.

I still remember the first time I heard of 'K' used for 1000 other than kilogram or kilometer was when the 'Y2K' bug threatened the entire world! I was curious to know and discovered that it was 'Year 2000 bug'. Since then, using 'K' for a thousand (anything) hasn't been an uncommon usage.

Good read is here on a [Math Forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20180101093624/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/60697.html)

Comment: @Maulik V How is this 'k' pronounced? For example: Can 20k simply be pronounced as 'twenty k'?

Comment: yes, 'K' as in alphabet. 'kay'. @Dinusha

Answer (score 8):

The SI prefix for a thousand is kilo-, officially abbreviated as k—for instance, prefixed to "metre" or its abbreviation m, kilometre or km signifies a thousand metres. As such, people occasionally represent the number in a non-standard notation by replacing the last three zeros of the general numeral with "k": for instance, 30k for 30,000.

Answer (score 6):

'K' is short for 1,000. It comes from 'kilo'.

Answer (score 3):

It's short for "thousand", just like how kilometers (km) are a thousand meters (m).

Answer (score 1):

Also, in computers K means 2**10 (two to the 10th power) = [1024](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1024_(number)). But in prices (or miles on car) it means 1000.

Answer (score -1):

As such, people occasionally represent the number in a non-standard notation by replacing the last three zeros of the general numeral with "K": for instance, 30K for 30,000.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! The other two answers from more than a year ago already mentioned this point; can you add more to the answer to make it stand out?

Comment: *Four* other answers, actually...from *two* years ago.